# How to use raw pixel data in pyglet to change image size

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I need to be able to change the width or height of an image before loading it into a sprite. I currently am using numpy to get either the center row or column and keep inserting it back into the image until it is the correct size. I do not know if this code even works yet, because I have also been having trouble loading the raw_image back into a sprite and displaying it.

```
def set_image_size(img, x, y):
    raw_img = img.get_image_data()
    format = 'RGBA'
    pitch = raw_img.width * len(format)
    rgba = np.array(list(img.get_image_data().get_data(format, pitch))).reshape(-1, raw_img.width, len(format))
    
    mid_y = rgba[round(raw_img.height/2),:] # This is needed to stretch along Y
    while rgba.shape[0] < y:
        rgba = np.insert(rgba, round(raw_img.height/2), mid_y, 0)
    mid_x = rgba[:,round(raw_img.width/2)] # This is needed to stretch along X
    while rgba.shape[1] < x:
        rgba = np.insert(rgba, round(raw_img.width/2), mid_x, 1)
    
    raw_img.set_data(format, pitch, ''.join(map(chr, rgba.tostring())))

    return raw_img
```

When I try blitting this onto an abstract image and blitting that to the screen, I get a weird striped red version of my image. I don't need to worry too much about quality, I just want to "stretch/tile" only the inside of the image so that the edges don't get warped. Also, my images are very small, only 15 by 15 pixels or so.

How can I fix either of these issues?

EDIT:

When I use sprite.scale, it gets stretched in weird ways:

```
self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.image, self.x, self.y, batch=batch)
self.sprite.scale_x = self.width / 16
```

Original Sprite:
[image: Original Sprite]

Stretched (with sprite.scale):

[image]

This isn't as much of a problem for this sprite, because I can use OpenGL Quads to draw it, but I need to start using more complex sprites that need to be scaled in the above way.

Comment: Why do you need to change it before you load it into a sprite when [pyglet.sprite.Sprite.scale](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/sprite.html#pyglet.sprite.Sprite.scale) is a thing?

Comment: @Torxed. I need to change it this way because my sprites get stretched out when I use scaling. I don't know if there is a way to avoid this, but the sprites in my game need to be rendered in practically any width or height without rounding out the edges. One sprite I tested scale on was pretty much just a rectangle, and I needed it to make the width longer, but it turned into an oval.

Comment: The scale should honor the aspect ratio, so there might be an issue there. Could you screenshot an example and post the relevant code?

Comment: @Torxed. Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get weird scaling artifacts. If it helps, I am attempting to recreate a game made in Construct 2, where the scaling appears to work this way. I added the examples of what happens above.

Comment: So the weird thing here is, you've probably turned off anti aliasing at some point in your viewport? Running a niminal working example with a similar image: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/de9ec3fcf79a5677e7113e7b1571f899 I can't reproduce this issue.  So some where you probably forgot to do `pyglet.gl.Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=4)` or [add texture filter parameters](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/de9ec3fcf79a5677e7113e7b1571f899#gistcomment-3300712)?

Comment: @Torxed, I tried changing the config by adding the result of `pyglet.gl.Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=4)` to the default parameters for my window class, and I added the texture filter parameters to the beginning of my code, but I can't tell any difference. I also tried changing the Y scale to less and scaling back up the entire image, but I get the same results. I think the problem may be related to how the image is very low resolution (16*7)

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention this haha. Yea, look at it this way. If I told you I was holding Mona Lisa in my hands standing across a football field and told you to paint a exact replica, would you be able to? :) I think this is a decent analogy of what you're asking Pyglet (OpenGL) to do in this case. I wasn't aware that you zoomed in the origin sprite, perhaps I should have guessed judging by the squares of the transparent area that this was the case. It's near impossible to to scale up small images without loss of quality, altho there are techniques, not something easily discussed tho.

Comment: I should mention tho that it is possible to some extent. Especially for simpler images. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem lies with the scale of the image resolution you're originally working with, being `16px` wide and `7px` high. Up-scaling an image by default won't do any clever [neighbor interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) and "fill in the blanks" in the way you expect it to.

To solve this, you can tell OpenGL that each new pixel in your up-scaled image should take "inspiration" from its neighbors. You do this by adding to your **render loop** the following each time you render the sprite:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST) 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
```

It's important that this is called before **every render** of the sprites you need to add the filter to. Not sure what the technical jargon is for this, but it has to be setup each render sequence, because the next time you loop over your render function it gets reset. There's a fancy word for this I'm sure of it.

Here's a working example:

```py
from pyglet import *
from pyglet.gl import *

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, width=800, height=600, fps=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) # Strictly speaking not needed, I think this is default or won't affect this test image in any significant way.

        self.keys = {}

        self.mouse_x = 0
        self.mouse_y = 0

        # The image itself is 800x400 originally
        # Positioned at x=0 and y=50 will place it at the bottom essentially
        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('test.png'), 50, 50, batch=None)
        self.sprite.scale = 20 # Scale the height, not the width

        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.mouse_x = x

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        try:
            del self.keys[symbol]
        except:
            pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

        self.keys[symbol] = True

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST) 
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        self.sprite.draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = main()
    x.run()
```

And here's a test-image you can use:
[image] *(<-- Small white square, not zoomed in for effect)*

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works a lot better and I no longer get curved edges. However, one of the reasons I think that tiling the inside row/column is necessary is that the border of the rectangle gets stretched on the edges because I need to use non-uniform scaling where the aspect ratio is different. But if there is no good way to change the pixel data, then this solution will probably work well enough.

Comment: Sadly none that I know of. If it was SVG or any other kind of vectors, it would be quite easy to accomplish what you need. But with pure `RGB(A)` data, what you need is near impossible unless someone's spent their life dedicating code to just solving that headache. Been where you are at btw, and I ended up using a mix of sprites (images) and `GL_TRIANGLES` to achieve what you want. Also mask layers to filter out unwanted artifacts is another ugly hack heh.